# Trying to display a log of the terminal output using python in textbox

Tags: python, tkinter, terminal, textbox

Hey im trying to display a textbox with the output of the terminal but it dosent work what am i doing wrong?

code:

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Loading")
root.geometry("600x400")

log = Text(root)
log.pack()

p = sub.Popen('../',stdout=sub.PIPE,stderr=sub.PIPE)
output, errors = p.communicate()

log.insert(tk.END, output)
log.config(state=DISABLED)
mainloop()
```

error:

> File "C:\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 1435, in _execute_child
> hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
> PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied

Comment: first mistake: you didn't show full error message.

Comment: what do you try to do with `Popen('../')`?  It expects some command but you put only path to folder. If you want to display some terminal then you have to run terminal or shell in `Popen` - ie. `Popen("bash")`  or `Popen("powershell")`

Comment: but Using `bash/powershell` may rather stop code. `Popen` may need command like `dir` or `ls` and tkinter will display result but after command will finish work.

Comment: @furas Im trying to display the terminal output of a running python script . that is located in one folder above